# NSFetchedController: Displaying Sections out of order

Tags: ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have three sections for an `Events` entity:

```
Upcoming  
Today    
Past
```

Here is FRC setup:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(_fetchedResultsController!=nil)
    {
        return  _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

     NSSortDescriptor *firstSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"modified"
                                                               ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:firstSort, nil];
     [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Using a Transient property for the Entity, I setup the the sections as:

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{    
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp)
    {
        NSDate *dateToCompare = [self getUTCFormateDate:[self modified]];
        NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        format.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
        NSString *stringDate = [format stringFromDate:now];
        NSDate *todaysDate = [format dateFromString:stringDate];

        NSUInteger differenceInDays =
        [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:dateToCompare] -
        [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:todaysDate];


        NSString *sectionString;

        switch (differenceInDays) {
            case -1:
                sectionString = @"Past";
                break;
            case 0:
                sectionString = @"Today";
                break;
            case 1:
                sectionString = @"Upcoming";
                break;
            }

        tmp = sectionString;
        [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Currently the `sections` appear in `descending` order, where `Upcoming` is first, then `Today`, and then `Past`. I'd like to show `Today`'s section first.

How can I display the sections in the following order?

Section 0:  `Today`

Section 1:  `Upcoming`

Section 2:  `Past`

Comment: you have to add a sort key that gives for example 0 to today 1 to upcoming and 2 to past and then sort by that key

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, I add another transient key "sectionOrder", just like I added the sectionIdentifier, and assign Today = 0; Upcoming = 1; Past = 2? And I use that key as the firstSort? Does sectionNameKeyPath remains the same? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing controlling the order is the sort descriptor you have:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *firstSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"modified"
                                                           ascending:NO];
```

So you need to change that. You can make it ascending, but you describe a sort order which isn't directly linked to the date.

Because what you describe is dependent upon the current date you will need to make some modifications so that you have order information stored persistently into the model and which you update each day. You can then add this as your first your sort descriptor to use that, and keep the existing sort descriptor for ordering inside each section.

The information you need to store is as per the comment from @Volker, with a simple index number for each section.

Comment: Thanks!  To clarify, I add another transient key "sectionOrder", just like I added the sectionIdentifier, and assign Today = 0;  Upcoming = 1; Past = 2?  And I use that key as the firstSort?  Does sectionNameKeyPath remains the same?

Comment: It needs to be persistent to be used for sorting. The transient is just for the section display name (and stays the same).

Comment: If the persistent attribute is called, let's say, "sectionOrder", how will I assign values to Today, Upcoming, & Past?

Comment: Similar to your logic for `sectionIdentifier` - that's why it needs to be updated each day...

Comment: So each day the App is launched, I fetch all the objects.  Loop through the array, compare the dates, and assign them appropriate section number in 'sectionOrder'.  I assign 'firstSort' to 'sectionOrder' and keep the existing sort as the 'secondSort' ?  Isn't this going to be slow?

Comment: You can be more intelligent with the fetch as anything older than 1 day or in the future by more than 1 day doesn't need to change (beware the user not opening the app for days). Also, you would want to batch if you modify a lot of items. You don't have too many options. You could run this on a background thread as the app starts up...